# Pandas: DataFrame.quantile axis keyword does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Any idea on why such a behavior?

**Base data:**

```
In  [1]: tmc_sum.head(6)
Out [1]:               1     2     3     8     9    10
         tmc                                          
         110+05759  7469  7243  7307  7347  7271  7132
         110P05759  7730  7432  7482  7559  7464  7305
         110+05095  7256  6784  6697  6646  6786  6530
         110P05095     0     0     0     0     0     0
         110+05096  6810  5226  5625  5035  5064  4734
         110P05096  6854  5041  5600  5308  5261  4747
```

**Prelude:**

As per the [documentation of quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html), this works correctly:

```
In  [2]: tmc_sum.quantile(0.05, axis=1)
Out [2]: 1     3347.50
         2     1882.40
         3     1933.10
         8     1755.00
         9     1554.15
         10    1747.85
         dtype: float64
```

It correctly computes the 5th percentile by columns. (Note that there are more columns than the six printed above.)

**Problem:**

But this doesn't work as expected:

```
In  [3]: tmc_sum.quantile(0.05, axis=0)
Out [3]: 1     3347.50
         2     1882.40
         3     1933.10
         8     1755.00
         9     1554.15
         10    1747.85
         dtype: float64
```

Which again computes by the column. Although, as per the documentation, it should compute by the row. So I tend to expect something like this:

```
In  [4]: tmc_sum.apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 0.05), axis=1).head(6)
Out [4]: tmc
         110+05759    7132.2775
         110P05759    7305.3175
         110+05095    6530.2900
         110P05095       0.0000
         110+05096    4734.7525
         110P05096    4747.7350
```

Is this behavior expected and am I missing something, or is it a bug?

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: @joris, 0.14. That's the latest, I suppose, correct? Here are the details:

Python version 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 17:27:11) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas version 0.14.0

Comment: No, there is a bug-fix release in the 0.14 series: 0.14.1, and as I noted in my answer the bug is fixed there.

Comment: I posted a reply before I read your answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in 0.14.0 (axis keyword was ignored) and is fixed in 0.14.1 (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7312)

If you can't upgrade, you can get the desired behaviour with `df.T.quantile(0.5)`.

---

BTW, it is the `axis=1` case that is not correctly. The default value of `axis=0` computes the quantiles for the different columns, `axis=1` computes it 'along the columns' for each row. Small example, consider:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
```

The default value of `axis=0`:

```
In [4]: df.quantile(0.5, axis=0)
Out[4]:
a    1.5
b    2.5
c    3.5
dtype: float64
```

And with `axis=1`:

```
In [5]: df.quantile(0.5, axis=1)
Out[5]:
0    1
1    4
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes. That's was another thing. I know that pandas uses `axis=0` for columns and `axis=1` for rows, I though they reversed it to avoid some other complexity. But I'm just a beginner!

Comment: The wording is also not that clear, I am not really a beginner, but also had to read it a few times to understand it ..

Comment: No, I didn't mean to say that you were a beginner. I am a beginner, and I'm currently taking Pandas at face value.

Comment: Ah, and I didn't mean to imply that I thought you meant that :-) It was just to say that the explanation was not that clear, so certainly for someone who is starting with pandas.